# are crawlers able to get all directories on webpage?

Tags: security, web-crawler

I want to backup some files on root of my webpage, something  like /www/mysite/myfolder/myfile.xls
Are crawlers able to find the directory? Even it is not used for files that are necessary for website?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A webcrawler without brute-force or dictionary trials (explained later) is able to find a file, if there exists **at least one link** to the file (on a page the crawler has visited before).

From the path `/www/myfolder/myfile.xls` I assume there might be even another problem. A webcrawler can only find files that are **publicly available**. Sometimes not all files under `/www`, `/var/www`, `/htdocs` or whatever is being used are publicly available. There might be structures like `/www/mysite/public`, where only `public` is available from the web. With such a structure one could make sure, that files in `/www/mysite` cannot be accessed without permission checks by PHP before the download.

So you have to check if

1. your directory can be accessed via HTTP/FTP or whatever
2. there exists a link to your file on another webpage the crawler can find (technically there must be one start page for the crawler of course)

### Exception: brute-force trials

There is an exception when also files without a link can be found: Search engines could try to find files by extending the already known URL-space of a domain by known words or random words. This of course can only be done sporadically. Consider a TinyURL generator. Usually these consist of a short known URL and some random characters. These short character sequences could be tried out by a search engine hoping to find files in the so called *deep web*. E.g. it's possible nobody has ever written the link http://example.com/f8fwy down anywhere, nontheless it could link to a real domain (if you are lucky some website or file that has never been linked to either).

However, with search engines offering mail providers (Google) or chat engines (Microsoft, Skype), I think this technique has become less important, because they could try to gain deep web links by these services.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So if I put my file inside publicly available directory (even there is no link to it on web) Web crawlers can find the directory (accessing directory tree somehow?) and download the file, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, they **could**, but you should not rely on it. So: If you want to make search engines find it, put a link to it. If you **do not want** search engines to find it, never put it in a directory publicly available (even if there is no link). If you want your friends to be able to download it, use a .htaccess/.htpasswd protection.

Answer (score 1):

Even without a link, simple file names simply can be brute forced by the help of dictionaries. There are some tools for such attacks like [Dirbuster](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_DirBuster_Project).